# Rails Year Make Model Dynamic Menus

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Calling all Rails superheroes! I'm racking my brains with this one and can't find a solution anywhere online...I want to build year/make/model drop-downs to select a car from a table of 30,000+ different cars. The table is called **car_variants**. [Here's a link to a similar thing on kbb.org](http://www.kbb.com/whats-my-car-worth/)

The **Year** is selected first which then populates the **Make** drop-down with those that were available in that year. This in turn populates the **Model** drop-down. All this filtering overcomes the dreadful problem of having the 30,000 car_variants in one unusable drop-down.

Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to post my entity diagram, but essentially...

- a car_make has many car_models
- a car_model has many car_variants
- a car_year has many car_variants

**SIDE NOTE** Since the car_variants table will be populated by importing an excel spreadsheet, I decided to join car_year to car_variants directly rather than saying a car_year has many car_models. That may or may not affect the challenge below.

The **car_variants** model ( a table of virtually every car since 1984) stores the **car_year_id** and the **car_model_id**. (car_make is obvious through car_model)

Now... along comes the user. They want to select their car from the car_variants table then add their car's **nickname** and **license_plate**. The user potentially has many cars so the car_variant_id's can't be stored in the user table. Instead we have a **car** table which contains the users cars.

- a car_variant has many cars (think of a car as being like an instance of a car_variant)
- a user has many cars

Ryan Bates did an excellent [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised) about Dynamic Select Menus. In his example (Countries and States), he used grouped_collection_select and some javascript. That certainly appears to be heading in the right direction for this challenge too, but this is more complex because there are more has_many relationships than **grouped_collection_select** seems to be able to handle.

I have successfully coded the car form with 3 drop-downs for year, make and model...

```
    <%= simple_form_for(@car) do |f| %>
      <%= f.error_notification %>
      <div class="form-inputs"> 

      <!-- select year to filter make dropdown -->
      <p>Year</p>
        <%= select_tag :car_year, options_for_select(CarYear.all.collect {|e| ["#{e.year}", e.id] }), :include_blank => true %>

      <!-- Select make to filter model dropdown -->
      <p>Make</p>
      <%= select_tag :car_make, options_for_select(CarMake.all.collect {|e| ["#{e.name}", e.id] }), :include_blank => true %>       

      <!-- Select model -->
      <p>Model (grouped collection select)</p>
      <%= f.grouped_collection_select :car_variant_id, CarMake.order(:name), :car_models, :name, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>        
      <%= f.input :nickname, :hint => "If you've given your car a nickname enter it here, otherwise just leave it blank." %>
        <%= f.input :plate %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
      </div>

       <div class="form-actions">
        <%= f.button :submit, "Add Car" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

...now how do I tie them all together so they filter one another then return the car_variant_id to be stored in the car_form.

After several late bleary nights, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the question through.

Comment: what's wrong with using some AJAX for that problem? it's pretty simple, you populate the first dropdown from within rails and load the others via ajax when changed.

Comment: Ajax will no doubt be part of the solution, but I'm not sure how to use ajax to do all that filtering and return the correct car_variant_id at the end of it all and submit it in the form. Would you use grouped_collection_select?